# Citus logs show error after upgrade to 11.2

Tags: postgresql, psql, postgresql-14, citus, postgresql-15

I have upgraded Citus extension from 10.2 to 11.2 running on postgres version 14. I disabled the version checks for citus and was able to apply the extension to database for the coordinator and workers nodes and than on coardinator node, I did run the below command to sync the metadata. However I ended up with errors in logs. (citus running in kubernetes)
How do I fix this error?
Restarting the pods didn't help

```
CALL citus_finish_citus_upgrade();
```

errors:

```
ERROR:  cache lookup failed for pg_dist_background_task, called too early?  
CONTEXT:  Citus maintenance daemon for database 16920 user 10  
LOG:  background worker "Citus Maintenance Daemon: 16920/10" (PID 562) exited with exit code 1  
LOG:  starting maintenance daemon on database 16920 user 10  
CONTEXT:  Citus maintenance daemon for database 16920 user 10  
WARNING:  cache lookup failed for pg_dist_cleanup, called too early?  
CONTEXT:  Citus maintenance daemon for database 16920 user 10
```